# Website with ScrollMagic pins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

Does anybody know how can I use ScrollMagic to have an effect like here http://appliancetecltd.com/. I want something like that, but I need more movement something like this [See Image](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ce4371i95), but I don't know how to use it, there is no much documentation about it's usage, can anybody help me?
I have some code here:

```
new ScrollScene({
            triggerElement: "span.pin-trigger",
            duration: 500,
            offset: 650
        });
        var moveleft = TweenMax.to("#pin-inner", 1, {
            left: leftpinpx,
            ease: Sine.easeInOut
        });
        new ScrollScene({
            triggerElement: "span.pin-trigger",
            duration: 950   
        }).addTo(controller).setPin("#pin-outer").setTween(moveleft);
```

but it is not working well, and I don't know how to make exact movement.