# jQuery ui draggable element gets under other draggable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a style problem with jQuery Ui draggable elements.
here what i have

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zbo7g5nz/1/)

As u can see, i have two droppable areas , in each area elements are draggable, and can drag and drop element from one block to another
The only problem here , that when i am dragging element from top block to below block, the dragging element gets under droppable are elements, but when i am dragging from bottom are to top there is no such problem.

Here is the code for dragging

```
$(".slide").draggable({
    // brings the item back to its place when dragging is over
    revert:true,
    // once the dragging starts, we decrease the opactiy of other items
    // Appending a class as we do that with CSS
    start: function(event, ui) { $(this).css("z-index", a++); },
    drag:function () {
        $(this).removeClass('droped');
    },
    // adding the CSS classes once dragging is over.
    stop:function () {
        $(this).addClass('droped');
    },
    zIndex: 10000,
    snapMode: "inner"
});
```

Can anybody help me please, i am working on it already 2 days, and can't figure out what is the problem, i have tried to change z-index positions of every block, but no result;

Comment: Your fiddle is not working, but you could try to give a z-index to the block you are trying to move and maybe to the one you want below too

Comment: remove the `z-index:2` from `ul.book_list` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/zbo7g5nz/3/)

Comment: Please do not circumvent the quality filter. This is not your first question and [you have included code directly in the question before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633120/website-with-scrollmagic-pins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that my code only worked the first time - i removed some z-indexes from your JQuery ánd your css, now it is working for me every time:

http://jsfiddle.net/zbo7g5nz/5/

---

My jFiddle doesnt seem to get updated to share.. Here is working code:

```
$(".slide").draggable({
        // brings the item back to its place when dragging is over
        revert:true,
        // once the dragging starts, we decrease the opactiy of other items
        // Appending a class as we do that with CSS
        start: function(event, ui) { $(this).css("z-index", a++); },
        drag:function () {
            $(this).parent().css('z-index', '10001');
            $(this).removeClass('droped');
        },
        // removing the CSS classes once dragging is over.
        stop:function () {
            $(this).parent().css('z-index', '10001');
            $(this).addClass('droped');
        },
        zIndex: 10000,
        snapMode: "inner"
    });
```

I gave a z-index to the `ul` holding the `li` that was higher than the `li` of the list that was below.

Comment: tnx, but ul has  z-index:2 already setted, i can't find what have u changed, please it u have solved and worked fiddle, update if and send me the like please, tnx

Answer (score 1):

Avoid tricks and go with divs instead of UL or LI for further compatibility.

Also, you don't need to listen to the start event to setup the z-index property. The .draggable() api exposes the [zIndex prop](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-zIndex) for that reason.

```
Here is the demo working:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zbo7g5nz/8/

Comment: You did kinda break the drag and drop, did you notice?

Comment: Please don't circumvent the quality filter just because the asker did the same. Links are meant to be clicked.

Comment: @randy yes, i noticed but it's just the clear:both on css. Remove that and you have it working ;)